# What's the difference between "questionable" vs "doubtful" injury designations in the NFL?

Tags: american-football, nfl, injuries

In the NFL, what is the difference between each of the designations for questionable vs doubtful? Which one is more severe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the NFL, there are injury designations. The injury designations indicate what percentage or chance that they'll play for that given day.

The [NFL](http://www.nfl.com/fantasyfootball/help/injuryreport) specifically has one that outlines them based on percentages:

> Inactive (IA) - Players are officially inactive for the current game and will not play
>   Out (O) – Not scheduled to play
>   Doubtful (D) – Players have approximately a 25% chance of playing
>   Questionable (Q) – Players have approximately a 50% chance of playing
>   Probable (P) – Players are very likely to start in the upcoming week

The injury designations are exactly that; based on percentages. Additionally, from  my experience they can change as the NFL week progresses: for better and worse.

Moreover, the [Wall Street Journal](http://online.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424053111904900904576554640692835656) has provided some insight regarding these injury designations as well:

> "Probable" means definite. "Questionable" is closer to probable. And
>   "doubtful?" If a player is listed as doubtful, like the Colts' Peyton
>   Manning is this week, then there's virtually no doubt whatsoever that
>   he's going to sit out.

In the NFL, teams are required to report injury statuses on a daily basis. Apparently, they shouldn't be taken literally:

> It's long been known that injury reports aren't to be taken totally
>   literally. The official NFL definitions are that "out" means a player
>   definitely won't play that week; doubtful means at least 75% chance
>   the player sits; questionable means 50-50 and probable means it's a
>   virtual certainty he'll play. Indeed, the Patriots famously have
>   listed quarterback Tom Brady as "probable" for years, even though he
>   made 111 straight starts at one point.